# Retrieve 5 most commented posts in seven last day with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have articles with comments. I would like to post 5 popular items on my home page based on reviews received over a 7 day period. Is it possible to do this with Laravel? I do not know how to deal with the query builder at all.

I have an article_id in each comment.

```
$mostPopular = Article::published()->whereHas('comments', function ($query){
        $query->count();
    })->orderBy($query, 'ASC');
```

thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Untested, but should satisfy your conditions. Let me know if you have any issues.

```
$popularArticles = Article::published()
    ->whereHas('comments')
    ->withCount('comments')
    ->where('created_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subWeek())
    ->orderBy('comments_count', 'DESC')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hello @Sandeesh, The solution has only worked for a while. After 7 days, articles are ignored. I do not understand why. Do you have a solution? (I want to display the most popular articles compared to comments received over 7 days but I do not want to ignore previous articles)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not much information regarding your model I will assume a few things. I haven't tested it but it should work.

```
$mostPopular = Article::published()
    ->selectRaw('articles.*, COUNT(comments.id) as comments_count')
    ->leftJoin('comments', function ($join) {
        $join->on('articles.id', '=', 'comments.article_id')
            ->where('comments.created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(7));
        })
    ->groupBy('articles.id')
    ->orderBy('comments_count', 'desc')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```